# How to Serialize HTuple in C#？

Tags: c#, serialization, halcon

Define the class：

```
    [Serializable]
    public class HalconConfig
    {

        public HTuple mNumber;
        public HObject mImage;

        public HalconConfig()
        {
            mNumber = 6;
            HalconFunction.BitmapToHObject(Resources.TestImage, out mImage);
        }
    }
```

And I want to save the HalconConfig object to a local file that can be read later

```
            HalconConfig _config1 = new HalconConfig();
            string _path = "./test.bin";

            BinaryFormatter _formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (FileStream s = File.Create(_path))
            {
                _formatter.Serialize(s, _config1);
            }

            using (FileStream s = File.OpenRead(_path))
            {
                HalconConfig _config2 = (HalconConfig)_formatter.Deserialize(s);
                BaseFunction.SendLog($"{_config2.mNumber}", LogLevel.Debug);
            }
```

But I failed。HTuple cannot be used after deserialization。

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK7on.png)

I tried binary serialization and Json serialization，but both failed。

Comment: why don't you want to store it as JSON?

Comment: @viveknuna Failed as well

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved. Essentially the reason was because I was using Halcon 18.11 and the provided dll was buggy and could not be serialized. I replaced it with Halcon 21.05 and the serialization function was implemented.

Answer (score -1):

Please check halcon documentation
https://www.mvtec.com/doc/halcon/13/en/serialize_tuple.html

you can serialize any tuple: HoperatorSet.serialize_tuple
and write the tuple to a file:
HoperatorSet.write_tuple

Comment: link only answers are not encouraged

Comment: Im sry i edited my answer. But The Link contains the docu for the needed function in two sentences.

Comment: The problem is that the link might become invalid some day and then your answer will get useless. StackOverflow is meant to be a long-lived collection of questions and answers.